# PATCH request method in Backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js, http-patch

What is the right way to perform `PATCH` request while saving model's attributes in Backbone.js?

Comment: Wow, Stack Overflow doesn't allow to post questions with all-caps words in title. Smart.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

As of Backbone.js v0.9.9, you can simply pass `{ patch: true }` to `save()`.

Read more: http://backbonejs.org/#changelog

Comment: `myModel.save(data, {patch:true})` shows up for me in Chrome's net panel as using an HTTP method of "OPTIONS", which doesn't seem right.

Comment: that OPTIONS is sent first as a PRE-FLIGHT. If passed, then PATCH will be sent.

Comment: but I get 400 bad request error, put however works fine @SimplGy

Answer (score 9):

In addition to [James Cropchos answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14306652/2236166) I want add the following, because [this stole some hours](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22566650/2236166) from me and maybe helps someone else:

If you use `model.save(attributesToPatchObject,{patch: true})` like it is possible since backbone v.0.9.9 as stated in James Cropchos answer, you may wonder how to determine which attributes have changed since the last call of `model.save()` to pass them in as `attributesToPatchObject` which is the first argument from `model.save()` (or `model.fetch()` if you didn't save the model lately).

Backbone itself didn't keep track of those attributes. I thought the method `model.changedAttributes()` could fit, but as the [backbone-doc says](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-changedAttributes) this method returns

> a hash of only the model's attributes that have changed since the last
>   set, or false if there are none

So this method didn't fit for this need. After some research I found out that backbone itself didn't keep track of *unsaved* attributes (I know, not a brilliant finding if I had read the docs more carefully).

I found out that [backbone.trackit](https://github.com/NYTimes/backbone.trackit) is a backbone plugin which exactly add the needed feature to backbone, by adding the method `unsavedAttributes()` to the model. The docs of backbone.trackit says about this method:

> Symmetric to Backbone's model.changedAttributes(), except that this returns a hash of the model's attributes that have changed since the last save, or false if there are none. Like changedAttributes, an external attributes hash can be passed in, returning the attributes in that hash which differ from the model.

It works like this:

```
//fetch an existing model from server
model.fetch({
  success : function(model, respose, options) {
    //tell backbone.trackit to track unsaved Attributes
    model.startTracking();
  }
});

//now some changes to the model happen
model.set("someProperty", "someValue");

/* save the model to server using the PATCH-Method 
   and only send the unsaved Attributes; 
   in this case only "someProperty" is sent
*/
model.save(model.unsavedAttributes(), {patch: true});
```

Since the `unsavedAttributes()` returns *false* if there are no unsaved Attributes, you could additionally wrap your `save()` statement within an if-condition which checks if `unsavedAttributes()` returns something other then *false* and only do your PATCH-Request if it's needed (because something changed).

NOTE: You didn't have to call `fetch()` to use `startTracking()` so you can use this method even with newly created models (`model.isNew()` returns true on that model), if there is a usecase for that.

Hopes this may save someone a little bit of research time.

Answer (score 8):

You'll have to override `Backbone.sync` and extend the existing method mapper

```
var methodMap = {
    'create': 'POST',
    'update': 'PUT',
    'delete': 'DELETE',
    'read':   'GET',
    'patch':  'PATCH'
};
```

you'll have to create your own patch method on a model like

```
Backbone.Model.prototype.patch = function(options) 
{
    // some code here that checks what attributes have changed since last save
    var xhr = (this.sync || Backbone.sync).call(this, 'patch', this, options);
    return xhr;  
}
```

I'm sure you can extend Backbone further to include `OPTIONS` and `HEAD` if you needed to

Note though, that even through jQuery supports the PATCH, OPTIONS and HEAD methods, your end-users' browser may not.