# How to use Backbone.js partial update (patch: true)?

Tags: javascript, rest, backbone.js, synchronization, http-patch

In the **save** method of the **Model** chapter, Backbone.js documentation says:

> If instead, you'd only like the changed attributes to be sent to the server, call model.save(attrs, {patch: true}). You'll get an HTTP PATCH request to the server with just the passed-in attributes.

Source: http://backbonejs.org/#Model-save

I could not find a good explanation of the way this actually works (and if it actually works!). It should send a PATCH request to the server with **just the passed-in attributes**, but it always sends a POST request to the server will **ALL the attributes** of the model. And with Firebug, I cannot see any difference when changing `Backbone.emulateHTTP`: Firebug always shows POST requests with the save method.

I created a test here: http://jsfiddle.net/r9kXL/
Note that the url does not exist of course, but the important is to see the POST request in Firebug.
As you can see, if you try to send only one attribute, it will always send everything to the server, making the option totally useless.

Why Backbone developers offer this options and what is it for? Could you show an example of its use?

Comment: When I read about the `{ patch: true }` option in the docs and try to figure out how it works, I ask myself how to determine *which* attributes I have to pass in order to send only the *unsaved* attributes to the server. If someone else want to now, you could read [this related answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22594139/2236166). Hopes this helps someone.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This happens because your model `isNew` and Backbone "creates new instance" (method `create`) instead of patching existing one (method `patch`). Take a look - http://jsfiddle.net/r9kXL/1/

```
'create': 'POST',
'update': 'PUT',
'patch':  'PATCH',
'delete': 'DELETE',
'read':   'GET'
```